# How to identify all identical lists from a list of lists?

Tags: python

Hi! I hava a list of lists, and when the first element of the sublists are equal, i need to add the second elements of those and print the results. I have thought about it for long, but i just can't seem to figure out how this could be done. Here's an example of my problem:

```
num_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [3, 4]]

# 0th and 2nd sublists both have 1 as their first element.
# sum = 2 + 2. print out 4.

# all the remaining sublists have 3 as their first element.
# sum = 4 + 4 + 4. print out 12.
```

Thank you very much!

PS: I'm aware that this kind of mapping would be better done with a dictionary, but this is just a simplified version of my problem. My actual program has sublists that have more than 2 values and i need to compare more than 1 value that need to be equal.

Comment: Can you  describe your full problem?

Comment: Sort them and use `itertools.groupby`

Comment: The actual lists in my problem are like the following:
['42x120x1800', 50, '50x90x800', 60], ['42x120x1800', 8, '50x90x800', 10]. And if the strings are equal, add the 1st elements of both lists and print, and add the last element of both lists and print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you did not describe your problem quite accurate enough.
Your real problem can only be grasped from your comments on both the question and the answer from @Blender. His nice solution for the problem works not immediately for what I understand is your problem case, ... but almost.

Here's a way to extend to suit your needs:

```
# some toy example data - I understand you want the first 2 sub_list
# to be "merged" because BOTH strings in pos 0 and 2 match
data = [['42x120x1800', 50, '50x90x800', 60],
        ['42x120x1800', 8, '50x90x800', 10],
        ['2x10x800', 5, '5x9x80', 6]]


from collections import defaultdict

# I'm using a lambda to initialize the items of the dict
# to a two-element list of zeros
d = defaultdict(lambda :[0, 0])
for sub_list in data:
    key = (sub_list[0], sub_list[2])
    d[key][0] += sub_list[1]
    d[key][1] += sub_list[3]

for key in d:
    print key, d[key]   
# ('2x10x800', '5x9x80') [5, 6]
# ('42x120x1800', '50x90x800') [58, 70]
```

If you then want to go back to the initial representation of the data:

```
new_data = [[key[0], val[0], key[1], val[1]] for key, val in d.iteritems()]
# [['2x10x800', 5, '5x9x80', 6], ['42x120x1800', 58, '50x90x800', 70]]
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I'm sorry i didn't describe my problem as it is. I thought that when i describe the problem too specifical to my program , the topic gets shut down :D.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

num_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [3, 4]]

d = defaultdict(int)

for item in num_list:
    d[item[0]] += item[1]
```

And the results are:

```
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {1: 4, 3: 12})
```

Comment: Yeah, this way you iterate only once, code is pretty clean, etc.. +1

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry, it's the first time i heard about defaultdict. What can i do with the results ? For example, how can i assign the 4 and 12 in your example to variables ?

Comment: @geekkid You can treat it just like a regular dict.

Comment: But if i have a lists of the following format : 
num_list = [['12x15x600', 2, '15x17x800', 4], ['12x15x600', 10, '15x17x800', 12]]. Is your solution still doable ? What i need is to add the integers in the same position if the -->both<-- strings are equal to strings in the other list in the same position. In this example, i need to add 2 + 10 and 4 + 12.

Comment: @geekkid: Try it out first. As long as they first elements are the same, the second elements in the list will add together. As I said before, don't simplify your problem so much. You'll get answers, but to the wrong problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use a dictonary for this task. Use tuples as keys:

```
>>> d = {(1,1): (2,2), (3,3): (4,4)}
>>> d
{(1, 1): (2, 2), (3, 3): (4, 4)}
>>> d[(1,1)]
(2, 2)
```

You might also want to learn about the [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class. If your elements are more complex, I suggest wrapping them in objects and implement the [`__add__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__) method to customize how they're added together.

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
c[(1,1)] = 10
c[(2,2)] = 10
c[(1,1)] += 1

c2 = Counter()
c2[(2,2)] = 4
c2[(2,3)] = 5
```

Which gives:

```
>>> c 
Counter({(1, 1): 11, (2, 2): 10})
>>> c + c2
Counter({(2, 2): 14, (1, 1): 11, (2, 3): 5})
```

Note that you cannot use Lists as keys, as lists are mutable and thus unhashable. You have to use tuples.

Comment: But, how can the problem be solved when instead of lists, dictionaries are used?

Comment: You can put whatever you want in the values of the counter, it just needs to implement ``__add__`` and ``__sub__``. In the keys, you need hashable values (i.e. tuples, numbers, …) however. This should give you the most flexible solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Using standard `dict()`:**

```
num_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [3, 4]]

d = dict()
for e in num_list:
    #get() checks if key exists, if not - returns 0        
    d[e[0]] = d.get(e[0], 0) + e[1]

print(d)
```

It prints:

```
{1: 4, 3: 12}
```